# MySql query uniq record base on field value

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have set alarm data , what i want is to get latest outstanding alarm,

```
    CREATE TABLE `alarm` (
  `alarmId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dT` time(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sevId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `alarmText` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of alarm
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `alarm` VALUES ('1', '00:48:05.000000', '1', 'alarm 1');
INSERT INTO `alarm` VALUES ('1', '01:48:17.000000', '2', 'alarm 1');
INSERT INTO `alarm` VALUES ('1', '02:48:34.000000', '3', 'alarm 1');
INSERT INTO `alarm` VALUES ('2', '00:48:00.000000', '2', 'alarm 2');
INSERT INTO `alarm` VALUES ('2', '00:52:07.000000', '1', 'alarm 2');
INSERT INTO `alarm` VALUES ('3', '16:49:24.000000', '2', 'alarm 3');
```

show latest alarm that does not have sevId 3(clear), What im trying so far is bellow, the result is good except for alarmId 2 should only return 1 alarm,

```
SELECT
    *
FROM    alarm
WHERE
    alarmId NOT IN (        SELECT alarmId FROM alarm WHERE sevId = '3'
    )
    -> ;
+---------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
| alarmId | dT              | sevId | alarmText |
+---------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
|       2 | 00:48:00.000000 |     2 | alarm 2   |
|       2 | 00:52:07.000000 |     1 | alarm 2   |
|       3 | 16:49:24.000000 |     2 | alarm 3   |
+---------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
```

expected result

```
+---------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
| alarmId | dT              | sevId | alarmText |
+---------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
|       2 | 00:52:07.000000 |     1 | alarm 2   |
|       3 | 16:49:24.000000 |     2 | alarm 3   |
+---------+-----------------+-------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try finding the max of dT in subquery and join it with the main table to get the row with max dT only.

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM
    alarm a
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        alarmId, MAX(dT) dT
    FROM
        alarm
    GROUP BY alarmId) b ON a.alarmId = b.alarmId AND a.dT = b.dT
WHERE
    a.alarmId NOT IN (SELECT 
            alarmId
        FROM
            alarm
        WHERE
            sevId = '3')
```

Without using `group by` and hence faster method:

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM
    alarm a
        LEFT JOIN
    alarm b ON a.alarmId = b.alarmId AND a.dT < b.dT
WHERE
    b.alarmId IS NULL
        AND a.alarmId NOT IN (SELECT 
            alarmId
        FROM
            alarm
        WHERE
            sevId = '3')
```